# using durandal and knockout but I can't set span text from a drop down change

Tags: select, binding, knockout.js, durandal

I'm trying to bind a value to a span tag by changing the position on the drop down.

My JS file code is

```
define(['plugins/router', 'durandal/app', 'knockout', 'durandal/system'], function (router, app, ko, system) {
    var Property = function (ref, title) {
        this.ref = ref;
        this.title = title;
    };

    var propertyList = [
        new Property("0", "sample"),
        new Property("1", "sasasfa"),
        new Property("2", "jgpjijo"),
        new Property("3", "uifhiuefh")
    ];

    var items = ko.observableArray(propertyList);
    var selectedProperty = ko.observable();

    return {
        router: router,
        items: items,
        selectedProperty: selectedProperty,
        activate: function () {
            router.map([
                { route: '', moduleId: 'viewmodels/propertydetails', title: 'Property Details', nav: true }            ]).buildNavigationModel();

            return router.activate();
        }
    };
});
```

My html is:

```
<div>
<div class="header-nav-items">
    <ul class="nav" data-bind="foreach: router.navigationModel">
        <li data-bind="css: { 'header-tab-active': isActive }">
            <a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, html: title"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div style="background-color: #E05000; padding: 3px; height: 25px;">
    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 10px; color: #ffffff;">
        <span id="title" data-bind="text: selectedProperty() ? selectedProperty().title : 'Unknown'"></span>
    </div>
    <div style="float: right; margin-right: 10px;">
        <select id="PropertyDDL" data-bind="options: items, optionsText: 'title', optionsValue: 'ref', value: selectedProperty, optionsCaption: 'Please select a property'"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm completely new to using Durandal and knockount. I'm trying to set the text of the span tag with the value title from PropertyList using selectedProperty().title but the value appears blank when I change the drop down to any position greater than 0. At pos 0 it displays unknown. If I replace selectedProperty().title with selectedProperty() then the ref prints out correctly on the span text. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All is much more simple. `optionsValue: 'ref'` means that selectedProperty() is 0, 1, 2 or 3.
Therefore `selectedProperty().title` is undefined and text is empty.
If you want to use `selectedProperty().title` just remove `optionsValue: 'ref'` from select.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I need the value of the option to hold the item number and text to be the name of the text. If I remove optionsValue: 'ref' that will remove the item number, won't it? Thanks.

Comment: You can find item number using `selectedProperty().ref`.

Answer (score 0):

Try encapsulating the text for your `title` span in a computed observable.  Like this:

```
var self = this;
self.titleText = ko.computed(function() {
    var prop = self.selectedProperty();
    return prop ? prop.title : 'Unknown';
});

<span id="title" data-bind="text: titleText"></span>
```

Knockout can be a bit quirky when you execute the observable in the binding expression itself, it doesn't always register the dependency properly such that the binding is notified when the underlying `selectedProperty` observable changes (in my experience).

Comment: Tried your variant in jsfiddle. Same empty text. See my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did try your suggestion by adding it to the activate function but unfortunately I'm getting the same results. However I noticed something, by prefixing it '1 -' shows title as undefined.